# iOS view does not fill the entire screen on iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an iOS static library, which I embed into a client application.  My static library contains a few xibs.  I built these xibs based on the iphone 5S screen size...with Auto Layout turned on for them.

However, after embedding them into the client application and running the app on iphone 6, my UI is displayed within the 320x568 portion of the iphone 6 screen, with white padding on the right side and bottom (I tried to attach the screenshot, but my reputation is too low).  I've tried several approaches to fix, but no avail.

I notice in the client app's plist, there's this entry:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
....
  <dict>
    <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
    <string>Default-667h</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
    <string>Portrait</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
    <string>{375, 667}</string>
  </dict>
....
</array>
```

If I change the UILaunchImageSize to {750, 1334}, which is the actual size of the image, then my xib fills the entire screen of the iphone 6.  Also, if I remove that section from the plist file, it works fine. Since this is a client app, I can't recommend any of these.

Has anyone run into this issue?  I really appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a xib or a launch image? Those are 2 separate things.

Comment: If the client hasn't configured their app correctly to support iPhone 6, how can you expect your framework to work in iPhone 6 size.  They need to fix their app

Comment: @Stonz2: The launch image in the client app causes cut-off issue for the xibs in my static library...I think so...because changing the size of the launch image in the plist to {750, 1334} seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Launch file. This is a requirement for iPhone 6.

File>New>File>User Interface>Launch Screen

Then add the file to in your project properties as the Launch File (same place where you specify the launch image).